# Solving this 3 variable diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can the given equation: $576k(y^3 - 51) = 288x + 82944k^2$ (where $x,y$ are integers and $k$ is some real number) be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Divide through by $288$ to get rid of those large numerical coefficients, rearrange the equation, and use the quadratic formula to solve for $k$. This will reveal the constraints on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I divided all sides of the equation as the last comment from @KeithBackman suggested, and then I treated it as a quadratic equation in terms of 'k'. I afterwards let, the square root part of the quadratic formula be equal to some variable, say 'n', so that I get (y^3 - 51)^2 - n^2 = 288x. Computer programs like Python etc. could generate some solutions but I am not proficient with coding.

Comment: What you should arrive at is that $(2y^3-102)^2$ must be greater than $1152x$ in order for the expression under the square root to be positive, i.e. so that $k$ can be real rather than complex. This tells you, for example, that $x$ can be any negative integer. See what else you can figure out about the relative values of $y$ and $x$.